# TypeError:null is not an object (evaluating LoginManager.logInWithPermissions)

Tags: javascript, react-native

1. i have run react-native link `react-native-fbsdk`.
2. i have also added dependency see below:

```
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
```

i am still getting error from `LoginManager.LogInWithPermissions` is not a function

Comment: Someone should help me out on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything nau works fine with nativescript android-sdk

It was android studio issue i think. i advice to use nativescript sdk inside of android studio for react-native devlopement

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup